# parse data-* with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I parse data-* attributes with JQuery? Is something like `$('a').attr('data-*').each(function(){...});` possible? Is there a simple method?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're trying to do something like this:

```
$('a').filter(function() {
    //if this function returns false, it will not be included in the set.
    return $(this).data().length > 0;
}).each(function() {
    //iterate over every matched DOM element
    //and iterate over their data attribute:
    $.each($(this).data(), function(key, value) {
        //do something with key and value here...
    });
});
```

Comment: There is a difference between [HTML5 `data-*`  attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) and jQuery [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) storage; I think the OP is asking about the former and you are answering for the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about data attributes ,

this jquery metata plugin is really good

```
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/metadata
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/6tv5y/1

```
<div id="mydiv" data-name="negative" data-from="stackoverflow"></div>

var mydata = $('#mydiv').data();
$.each(mydata ,function(i) {                               
        alert(mydata[i]);
});
```

**UPD:** Note that it is supported only since jQuery 1.4.3.